# Using cuid to replace mongoose ObjectIds

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I was thinking of using cuid (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cuid) to replace mongoose's naturally generated objectids, so that `_id` in my model would get a cuid rather than a generated one.

Questions:

1. How do you achieve this
2. Are there any side effects
3. How would this affect population??

Is 1 as simple as:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cuid from 'cuid';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export const departmentSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: 'String', default: cuid(), required: true },
  name: { type: 'String', required: true },
  sector: { type: 'String', required: true },
});
```

??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've had success using the following to use a CUID instead of _id:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cuid from 'cuid';

const gymSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: 'String', required: true, default: cuid },
}):
```

The difference being that I simply pass the function, whereas you call the function. I made that mistake at first...

I can confirm that population works as expected, but the question that I can't answer is whether there are any side effects. And possibly, more importantly, why you would want to do this. [mern.io](http://mern.io) uses CUIDs instead of the `ObjectId`, but they do it awkwardly in another field. I don't know why the `ObjectId`s aren't appropriate. Anyone?